# Facebook Pixel loads twice

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel, google-datalayer

I'm [using Facebook pixel with Google Tag Manager](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1021909254506499) , everything is working perfectly except that some times FB pixel loads twice with no Pixel Id

[image]

1. In Google Tag Manager **Facebook pixel base code** `Tag firing options` is set to `Once per page`.
2. Every tag that I'm using is set to fire after **Facebook pixel base code** in `Advanced Settings > Tag Sequencing > Fire a tag before [My tag Name] fires > Setup Tag` = **Facebook pixel base code**
3. Facebook version is `n.version='2.0';`
4. `URL Called:` in `Facebook Pixel Helper` is something like this *https://www.facebook.com/tr/?batch=1&rqm=GET&dt=[SomethingRandom]*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one pixel on your website.

The “ghost” one is the result of your cache and the way Pixel Helper works. PH is looking for any code that resembles a pixel and tries to test it. The cache is probably changing some parts of the code, creating this confusion.

In reality, it does nothing and it doesn’t affect you in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not discounting everything on caches and get a deep understanding of when your pixel is firing and why. Many pixels fires might be caused for example by activating the advanced pixel matching which will cause a pixel to look for any form fields on your page be sent back to FB:
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/611774685654668

With Google Tag manager you have to be twice as careful as it's super easy to screw up things by placing tags and vars all over the place and not keeping track which tags fire on which URLs.